# How to build a compound WHERE clause that is limited to the current record

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an (example) application that sends baseball scores to users. The use is able to select which inning the score should be sent for some specific teams (e.g. 'Send me Yankee scores after 7 innings). There is also a setting for 'All other' teams (e.g. 'Send me scores for any other teams after 8 innings).

These settings are saved to a table which stores the user, a team ID, and the number of innings. Team ID '99' is used for 'All other teams'. So our user's records would look like:

```
**User - Team - Innings**

Bob - 13 (Yankees) - 7

Bob - 99 (all other teams) - 8
```

Now it comes time to check the scores and send some notifications. I find that the Yankees game has reached the end of the 7th inning and fire off a message to Bob.

20 minutes later, that same Yankees game has reached the 8th inning. Bob should NOT receive a message this time, since he got one after 7 innings.

Now consider Julie:

```
**User - Team - Innings**

Julie - 13 (Yankees) - 8

Julie - 99 (all other teams) - 7
```

Julie has used the settings to say 'send me all scores after 7 innings, except for Yankees scores which should wait until 8 innings'. This time, after 7 innings in the Yankees game, Julie should NOT receive a notification.

Finally, Dirk. Dirk is a little confused:

```
**User - Team - Innings**

Dirk - 13 (Yankees) - 7

Dirk - 99 (all other teams) - 7
```

His Yankees setting is pretty redundant, but whatever - as long as he doesn't receive the same notification twice, he's fine.

---

The Yankees game has just completed the 7th inning. What is the best way to query my table and decide who needs to get alerts?

I am fairly new to SQL, but I *think* I can make a plain-language representation:

Send alerts to:

> Any people that care about the team A team after X innings, unless
>   they also care about ALL teams after < X innings (they would already
>   have received an alert)
>
> PLUS
>
> Any people that care about ALL teams
>   after X innings, unless they also care about team A after < X innings
>   (they would already have received an alert)

(I don't think this actually covers Dirk's scenario though?)

My best guess is that I need to make a WHERE clause that matches the team AND the innings, but then also tests if there is a record in the same table *for the same user* that meets the criteria above.

This is way beyond me - I don't even know what techniques to google. I couldn't even come up with a decent question title :/

Comment: I think that the major flaw is in the table design. the fact that the id '99' which by table definition should be a team id and instead is "everybody" is cause of confusion and surprising behavior. Can you think of a different table / database structure to accomplish the same task?

Comment: Please, don't use *magical numbers* like 99 to represent something like that. If anything you should employ `NULL` meaning "no specific team" for this purpose. An example of this coming back to haunt you is when people get license plates like "999 999" and start getting piles of tickets because that's used to represent "no plate".

Comment: Yes, I too am not in love with it and might see if I can get it changed. Would still like to know how to do something like this though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by making a select that shows specific team settings plus general team settings. You can do that by joining the table on itself.

```
select s.*, g.innings as g_innings 
from settings s join settings g 
on (g.user = s.user and g.team = 99) -- 'g.team is null' would be better, yes...
```

The rest is easy: use this select twice with appropriate where clauses, and union the result.

**EDIT**: use a single query and OR the two where clauses.

```
select s.*, g.innings as g_innings 
from settings s join settings g 
on (g.user = s.user and g.team = 99) -- 'g.team is null' would be better, yes...
where (s.innings = X AND g.innings >= X) 
OR (g.innings = X AND s.innings >= x)
```

Comment: Thanks - can you explain why a union of two statements is required? Can't I just use a where clause that says `(s.innings = X AND g.innings >= X) OR (g.innings = X AND s.innings >= x)` - what am I missing?

Comment: Euh, yes, I think you're right, an OR will do. It will even be better because it will avoid the duplicate where s.innings == g.innings == x. Updated the answer...